# delete script msgbox upgrade idea?

Tags: vbscript

I have a script to remove outdated files, but I would like to upgrade it and I'm stuck.

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oFileSys = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sRoot = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\LOGS\test"
today = Date
nMaxFileAge = 1

DeleteFiles(sRoot)

Function DeleteFiles(ByVal sFolder)
  Set oFolder = oFileSys.GetFolder(sFolder)
  Set aFiles = oFolder.Files
  Set aSubFolders = oFolder.SubFolders

  For Each file in aFiles
    dFileCreated = FormatDateTime(file.DateCreated, "2")
    If DateDiff("d", dFileCreated, today) > nMaxFileAge Then
      objShell.Popup "Old file will be deleted after clicking ok",, "Warning"
      file.Delete(True)
    End If
  Next

  For Each folder in aSubFolders
    DeleteFiles(folder.Path)
  Next
```

I upgraded this script by adding

```
objShell.Popup "Old file will be deleted after clicking ok",, "Warning"
```

this popup box but of course now I have to click on OK as many times as many files are to delete...

I would like to have this popup only once, then after clicking OK, everything is automatically deleted.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing: with your current code the file would be deleted regardless of whether you do or don't click OK. You need to check which button was actually clicked and react accordingly. You may also want a `MsgBox` with "Yes" and "No" buttons instead of a popup.

```
res = MsgBox("Delete files?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Warning")
If res = vbYes Then
  file.Delete True
End If
```

To avoid having to confirm each file separately you need to move the confirmation dialog before the loop:

```
res = MsgBox("Delete files?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Warning")
If res = vbYes Then
  For Each file in aFiles
    If DateDiff("d", file.DateCreated, today) > nMaxFileAge Then
      file.Delete True
    End If
  Next
End If
```

If you want to ask for confirmation only if files matching your criteria are found, you can either use a flag variable to indicate whether or not to delete the files:

```
Dim doDelete
For Each file in aFiles
  If DateDiff("d", file.DateCreated, today) > nMaxFileAge Then
    If IsEmpty(doDelete) Then
      res = MsgBox("Delete files?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Warning")
      If res = vbYes Then
        doDelete = True
      Else
        doDelete = False
      End If
    End If
    If doDelete Then file.Delete True
  End If
Next
```

or you can collect the matching files in a list and process that list after asking for confirmation:

```
Set toBeDeleted = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each file in aFiles
  If DateDiff("d", file.DateCreated, today) > nMaxFileAge Then
    toBeDeleted.Add file
  End If
Next

res = MsgBox("Delete files?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Warning")
If res = vbYes Then
  For Each file in toBeDeleted
    file.Delete True
  Next
End If
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you... but now he will ask every time no matter if there are some files to delete or not.... I want him to ask only when there are some outdated files...

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!

heres solution:

```
Dim bConfirmed
bConfirmed = False

For Each file in aFiles
 If DateDiff("d", dFileCreated, today) > nMaxFileAge Then
  If Not bConfirmed Then
   objShell.Popup "Old file will be deleted after clicking ok",,"Warning"
     bConfirmed = True
  End If
 file.Delete(True)
End If
```

he is asking only one time ( if there are any outdated files ) and don't repeat question for every file.

Comment: That will still unconditionally delete the files, regardless of whether the user pressed "OK" or "Cancel".